# Can an interface status be active without an IP address assigned to it?

Tags: networking, ifconfig

Looking at the output of `ifconfig` or `ip link show`. Can an interface status be UP/RUNNING/active without an IP address assigned to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be UP and RUNNING without an IP address. This can even be useful, e.g. if you are just interested in sending/receiving layer 2 frames, or if you are running a different layer 3 protocol than IP.

Comment: Or if you're about to broadcast a DHCP request.